# Lumen unable to upload > 2MB

Tags: php, angularjs, lumen

I have a Lumen app handling file uploads and it is working perfectly fine for files below 2MB. But when I try to upload to file > 2MB, I am getting the following validation failed and the file is not getting uploaded,

```
   $this->validate($request, [
       'file'           => 'required'
   ]);
```

Response is

```
{"file":["The file field is required."]}
```

I have verified `php.ini` file and it has been set to accept files upto 20MB

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

I have also restarted apache and verified if the above `php.ini` is being loaded via phpinfo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u sure that php.ini in /etc/apache2/ directory???

Comment: No. It is inside /etc/php/7.0/apache2/

But replacing the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/ with  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini fixed the issue. Strange.

Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Lumen uses CLI Console php.ini